# XSL into a div style

Tags: xml, html, xslt

Can one do the following using XSL?

I have an XML with the following:

```
<main
     template.main.style="width: 1000px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;">
   <child
      template.item.style="duration: 7200; animation: all;"/>
</main>
```

Can the values of for instance `template.main.style` or `template.item.style` be formatted with xsl inside a div so it will look like this?

```
<div id="main" style="width: 1000px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="layer" style="duration: 7200; animation: all;">
```

If so how, all help is much appreciated..

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Have you tried something that hasn't worked? On SO you want to show that you have at least a minimal understanding of the problem being asked. [You can check out this question for things to include in your question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need more info.  But it is possible.  For example you can do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="main">
      <div>
         <xsl:attribute name="style">
            <xsl:value-of select="@template.main.style" />
         </xsl:attribute>
      </div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="child" />
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="child">
      <div>
         <xsl:attribute name="style">
            <xsl:value-of select="@template.item.style" />
         </xsl:attribute>
      </div>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```